# How to realease java threads from executor service thread pools?

Tags: java, android, junit, threadpool, executorservice

My android app uses a thread fixed pool with a small number of threads (about 32 so). my app sends tcp/ip messages to other tablets on a dedicated wifi network.

When I run tests on my pc with a dozen or so *instances of the objects* that the app uses, I am left with about 1000 threads after i shut down the executor service for each instance of the objects. I am concerned that these may affect subsequent tests.

in any case, I would like to give these threads back to the jvm when in the teardown method of the tests.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: 'When the app shuts down' means that the JVM has also shut down and also that all the threads have exited. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: An ExecutorService can be shut down, which will cause it to reject new tasks. Two different methods are provided for shutting down an ExecutorService. The shutdown() method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute before terminating, while the shutdownNow() method prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks. Upon termination, an executor has no tasks actively executing, no tasks awaiting execution, and no new tasks can be submitted. An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources.

Comment: when i stop the app during testing on the pc and  shutdown the executor service, the threads are still around.

Comment: @RayTayek Not under the normal definition of 'stop the app'. What's yours? And where's your evidence?

Comment: sorry about the confusion, please edit for clarification.

Comment: oops, i meant please see the recent edits i made.